# How to draw this in html5 canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

How do I draw this in html5 canvas?
I can only do the rectangle with round corners part.

[image: What I want to draw]

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function roundRect(x, y, w, h, radius)
 {
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var r = x + w;
 var b = y + h;
 context.beginPath();
 context.strokeStyle="green";
 context.lineWidth="4";
 context.moveTo(x+radius, y);
 context.lineTo(r-radius, y);
 context.quadraticCurveTo(r, y, r, y+radius);
 context.lineTo(r, y+h-radius);
 context.quadraticCurveTo(r, b, r-radius, b);
 context.lineTo(x+radius, b);
 context.quadraticCurveTo(x, b, x, b-radius);
 context.lineTo(x, y+radius);
 context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+radius, y);
 context.stroke();
 }
 roundRect(10, 10, 200, 100, 20);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer rounded corners there is a easier way: you may use the context method `arcTo()`For example to draw a rectangle with rounded corners you can write:

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 function roundRect(x, y, w, h, r){

 var x0 = x, y0 = y;
 var x1 = x0+w, y1 = y0;
 var x2 = x1, y2 = y0+h;
 var x3 = x, y3 = y2;
       
 ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
 ctx.lineWidth=4;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(x3,y3-r);
      
 ctx.arcTo(x0,y0,x1,y1,r);
 ctx.arcTo(x1,y1,x2,y2,r);
 ctx.arcTo(x2,y2,x3,y3,r);
 ctx.arcTo(x3,y3,x0,y0,r);
 ctx.stroke(); 
   }
  

roundRect(10, 10, 200, 100, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

However the image of the 2 rectangles may be done using 2 simple canvas rectangles and an SVG filter like this:

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.fillStyle = "green";
 ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100)
 ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 30, 30)
```

```css
canvas{filter: url(#goo);}
```

```html
<svg width="1" height="1">
<defs>
<filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" 
                     values="1 0 0  0   0  
                             0 1 0  0   0  
                             0 0 1  0   0  
                             0 0 0 40 -28" result="goo" />
      
    </filter> 
  </defs>
</svg>
<canvas id="c" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

If you are not familiar with The Gooey Effect you may read this article: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/

I hope this helps

Comment: Note that (in modern browsers) you could integrate the gooey only for this shape by setting your context's `filter` to your svg filter, and drawing the context over itself using drawImage and globalCompositeOperation=copy  https://jsfiddle.net/Levfqj0w/

Comment: Or even using a single path declaration + gCO cleaning: https://jsfiddle.net/2w54h9zL/

Comment: It didn't work. can you separate the code? What goes inside the script, what goeson the html body, and where does this part go? canvas{filter: url(#goo);}

Comment: Thank you Max for your feedback. Please run the code snippet  to see how it works. The code is already separated. If you refer at the second snippet the first part, the one beginning with `var canvas...` is JavaScript. the second part containing `canvas{filter: url(#goo);}`is the css. The third part beginning with `<svg width="1" height="1">` is the HTML